# "in" vs. "within" for data and information

Tags: word-usage, difference

I wrote this sentence

> In our approach, we try to simulate the way a human user scans a web page to find specific data items. We use textual delimiters and semantic cues **(in or within ?)** the content to identify the data of interest.

In a text/page/content/book, some words/information/data/delimiters are "in" or "within" it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a slight difference.  While "**in**" points to the origin or the overall relationship between the subject and the object (*cues* and *content* in your case), **within** imposes (or implies) additional boundary, a limitation, meaning *certainly not outside*, *contained by*, *fully enclosed*.

Idioms like *within confines of*, or *within limits*, or *within boundaries* most likely contribute to that.

I, like Aleksey, think that '*in*' is appropriate.  Shorter, more familiar, less elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

In and within generally depend on the context. In this example, we would say ***within** the content*. In other contexts, we would say 'in', for example we wouldn't say *the biscuits are within the tin*, we'd say *the biscuits are in the tin*. Just depends on how it's being used

Answer (score 0):

Either one will do, though I prefer **in** for the sake of simplicity